# ReCaptcha 2 working only once

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement a ReCaptcha but I can only get a valid *g-recaptcha-response* once when I'm testing it. If I'm trying to validate the captcha a second time, I check the box "I'm not a robot" then resolve the challenge but I'm getting the exact same *g-recaptcha-response* as the first time and I get a "timeout-or-duplicate" error from the webservice https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify.

The only way I can get it to work again is to empty my local storage and my cookies.
Do you have any idea of why I have to do this ?

My code look like this :

HTML:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha"></div>
```

JS:

```
class CaptchaProtectedForm {
    onSubmit() {
        const captchaContainer = document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha');
        this.captchaWidgetId = global.grecaptcha.render(capContainer, {
            sitekey: '{site key}',
            callback: this.doSubmit.bind(this),
        });
    }

    doSubmit() {
        const response = global.grecaptcha.getResponse(this.captchaWidgetId);
        this.callBackend(parameters, response);
        global.grecaptcha.reset();
    }
}
```

Backend code (express router) :

```
router.route('/captchaProtectedEndpoint').post((req, res) => {
    const {
        headers: {
            'x-captcha-token': captchaToken,
            'x-forwarded-for': forwardedIp,
        },
    } = req;

    const requestData = {
        secret: conf.captchaSecretKey,
        response: captchaToken,
        remoteip: forwardedIp || req.connection.remoteAddress,
    };

    const requestConfig = {
        uri: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
        method: 'POST',
        form: requestData,
    };

    request(requestConfig)
        .then((captchaResponse) => {
            if (captchaResponse.success) {
                console.log('success', captchaResponse);
                res.status(200).send();
            } else {
                console.log('failure', captchaResponse);
                res.status(403).send();
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send();
        });

});
```

*Late edit:*
The code works as expected, it was not working because of another module that was messing up with the local storage of our app.

Comment: Can you post your code? Without is a problem, solve your problem :) Anyway, you must reset it when you submit your form, so you can solve new one (if we're talking about ajax, else the page is reloaded).

Comment: I have added some code :) Yes the captcha validation is done in AJAX. But even after reloading the page, if I redo the captcha challenge, the _g-recaptcha-response_ is still exactly the same except if I clear my local storage and cookies.

Comment: by any chance do you have same key on multiple domains

Answer (score 4):

This happens because, the g-recaptcha prevents duplicate entries. If you refresh the page and try to validate it, it will start the validation from the beginning. Also, if the data is stored in your cookies, the recaptcha will not start a fresh validation.

Comment: Sadly even after a refresh I still have the same problem. I don't know which data google stores in the cookies but I think that I shouldn't have to clear my cookies to be able to send my captcha-protected form a second time...

Comment: Having your cookies won't prevent you from using recaptcha for the second time but, sometimes it will consider you as a 'bot' trying to access the validation form. It is programmed such a way to prevent bots and spams.

Comment: Each reCAPTCHA user response token is valid for two minutes, and can only be verified once to prevent replay attacks. If you need a new token, you can re-run the reCAPTCHA verification.